# Walktrap community detection in networkx

Tags: python-3.x, networkx

I am looking for walktrap community detection algorithm implementation for weighted graphs in networkx(python 3.6) . I know that walktrap is implemented in graph but I haven't found its implementation in networkx. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no community detection method based on walktrap algorithm in `networkx`. If you need community detection, you can use:

- [Default `networkx` algorithms](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/community.html) (Kernighan–Lin algorithm, Girvan–Newman method etc)
- [Louvain-based algoritms](https://python-louvain.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html) for `networkx` (you need the `python-louvain` module for them)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will convert my graphs to igraph format